# receive from multiple UDP endpoints

Tags: c#, udp

my question applies to this piece of code:

```
using DSemulator;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Stuff
{
public class interfaceServer
{
        int portNumber = 8000;
        IPEndPoint ipep, iclient;
        UdpClient clientUdp;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        List<UdpClient> clients = new List<UdpClient>();

        public interfaceServer()
        {
                ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAdress.Any, portNumber);
                iclient = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                clientUdp = new UdpClient();
                clientUdp.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                clientUdp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

                clientUdp.Client.Bind(ipep);

                worker.DoWork += delegate { worker_DoWork(clientUdp, iclient); };
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_DoWork(UdpClient udpClient, IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint)
        {
                bool read = true;
                while (read)
                {
                        Byte[] data_rec = new Byte[128];
                        try
                        {
                                data_rec = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndpoint);
                        }
                        catch (SocketException)
                        {
                                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                                UdpClient tempClient = new UdpClient();
                                tempClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                                tempClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                                tempClient.Client.Bind(endpoint);

                                worker.DoWork += delegate { worker_DoWork(tempClient, endpoint); };
                        }

                        //do interesting stuffzz
                        //the UdpClient and remoteEndpoint need to be passed to objects of another class.
                        //these objects handle sending data back
                }
        }
}
}
```

Due to company-secrets, I can not show the whole code, but this is where my problem lies.

I have a program, who simple said must receive Udp packages. The packages can be send from any IP-adress and from any portnumber. There is also no way to say how much connections there will be. All these connections need to be processed at the same time (same time, for us as humans), I cannot wait until one socket has received something and then move on to another receive, that's why I implemented the threads.
Messages will be received on a single port, 8000 in this case.

In the code I have made, I made a try-catch statement for receiving messages. The 'try' part will fail if there is a message received from another IP/port, so in the catch I make another socket and thread for this other IP/port.

I think this is a good solution, or at least the start of one, but I'm still wondering over some stuff.

1. How do I start the added thread? I can not wait for all threads to finish, then call worker.RunWorkerAsync(); again. If I do that, lot of information can be lost, so that's no option.
2. Because the 'try' will fail in all threads, there will be lots of threads made for a single socket. How do I solve that?

Also, if I am totally thinking in the wrong direction, I'd be glad to hear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the code into your question so we don't have to go off to a third party site to view it.

Comment: was already busy with it, but thanks JMK :)

Comment: Looking at your code, the complete absence of any kind of asynchronous IO is probably problematic if performance is an issue. Running async delegates in a tight loop on the ThreadPool is likely to consume all ThreadPool threads under load and thus to cause severe thread starvation causing all ThreadPool dependent APIs to become sluggish and unresponsive. Be warned: ThreadPool is everywhere in .Net. If performance is essential, this isn't a good start. Really, SO isn't a code review site (but this question could be modified to seem less like that what it's asking for)

Comment: Note: Running synchronous IO operations on async delegate invocations simply shunts the synchronous IO onto the ThreadPool, where such blocking code doesn't belong.

Comment: Should this be moved to the code review beta?

Comment: @spender if you look at my code, I don't do ANY I/O, that is in the part which I left out. That also isn't my problem. And I certainly don't see SO as a code review site. I may have just registered but I'm certainly no 16year old boy who just learned programming and dumps every little question he has on this web. - or I just don't understand you, in which case I'd like some more explanation

Comment: @JustAJ `UdpClient.Receive` : "The Receive method will block until a datagram arrives from a remote host" This is by definition, a synchronous IO call. You're calling this method in a loop on threads that will run in the ThreadPool. This will block the ThreadPool leading to issues I describe above.

Comment: For better performance, adopting async/await and using the ReceiveAsync will greatly improve performance under load: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receiveasync.aspx

Comment: @spender ah ofcourse. What I didn't knew is that it blocks the whole ThreadPool. So it blocks all threads, instead of the thread it is receiving on? Because I was trying to only block the thread it is 'in', so to say

Comment: @JustAJ : By calling RunWorkerAsync, you are asking that the code you are invoking will be run on the ThreadPool. If your code blocks, it will increase pressure on the ThreadPool to spawn new Threads to deal with its work queues in a timely fashion. Because the ThreadPool spins up new threads quite slowly, this introduces latency in IO operations and sluggishness in the rest of your app. Blocking code in the ThreadPool is a big no-no for fluid server applications. You should always release ThreadPool threads quickly. Only true async IO can do this. Learn about async/await and use this if poss.